# jQuery POST from Javascript show error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is working properly. But I want to make it a function and more generic. So I have tried once again in my next code. but that is not working at all. See my next code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Create Sensor</h2>

    <form id="form">
        <form enctype='application/json'>
            <input name='version' value='1.0.1'>
            <input name='sensors_sensor' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_name' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_type' value=''>
            <br>
            <input id="input" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Sensor" />
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#input').click(function() {
                    var fromData = {
                        "version": $('input[name=version]').val(),
                        "sensors": [{
                            "sensor": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                            "output": [{
                                "name": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                                "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()
                            }]
                        }],

                    };

                    var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                    alert(fromDatan);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "abc.com",
                        headers: {
                            "x-api-key": "abcd=",
                            "content-type": "application/json"
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        data: fromDatan,

                        success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is not working:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Create Sensor</h2>

    <form id="form">
        <form enctype='application/json'>
            <input name='version' value='1.0.1'>
            <input name='sensors_sensor' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_name' value=''>
            <input name='sensors_type' value=''>
            <br>

            <button onclick="postSOS();">Create</button>
        </form>
        <script>

        function postSOS() {
          postSEN();
        }



        function postSEN() {

               // $('#input').click(function() {
                    var fromData = {
                        "version": $('input[name=version]').val(),
                        "sensors": [{
                            "sensor": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                            "output": [{
                                "name": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                                "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()
                            }]
                        }],

                    };

                    var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
                    alert(fromDatan);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "abc.com",
                        headers: {
                            "x-api-key": "abcd=",
                            "content-type": "application/json"
                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        data: fromDatan,

                        success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                //});
        }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What is wrong with the 2nd piece of code?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rv7hL3v7/

Comment: For me it only alerts the fromDatan, the `success` function is not triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the whole ajax code inside a function and call that when the button is clicked.
Executing http://jsfiddle.net/xmkn3mu4/1, an alert with the source code of abc.com is opened.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('button').click(function(){
        request();
    });
});


function request() {

    var fromData = {
        "version": $('input[name=version]').val(),
            "sensors": [{
            "sensor": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                "output": [{
                "name": $('input[name=sensors_name]').val(),
                    "type": $('input[name=sensors_type]').val()
            }]
        }],
    };

    var fromDatan = JSON.stringify(fromData);
    alert(fromDatan);
    $.ajax({
        url: "abc.com",
        headers: {
            "x-api-key": "abcd=",
                "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: fromDatan,

        success: function (fromData, status, jqXHR) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        }
    });
    return false;

};
```

Comment: not working bro, it is executing trigger even before putting data in form

Comment: @anupam_on Sorry, my mistake. I forgot the event handler. It's updated.

Comment: YES it is working, Thanks a lot my friend :)
As I am not having 15 reputations yet, couldn't vote up your answer. sorry for that :(

Comment: Yeah, know exactly what you mean :)

Comment: but this one is not working. the same code you have given: http://pastebin.com/W7xLKEDN
tried with compileonline

Comment: Working now after deleting
    <form id="form">
        <form enctype='application/json'>

Comment: Just wanted to type that in :)

Answer (score 0):

Because when click button in 2nd piece of code, it doesn't prevent default submit. postSOS should return false to prevent it.

```
function postSOS() {
    return postSEN();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `<script type="text/javascript">` to properly declare the js functions under your `<script>` tag.

Comment: Although this is an answer to the question, it doesn't solve the problem.